# How to add custom, but not-required, method to jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am adding in a custom method for the jQuery Validation plugin to check for a valid phone number.  However, I want this field to be optional, and not required.  For some reason, when I add the following code in, it is making fields with the class "phone" required too.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$.validator.addMethod("phone", function(ph, element) {
    var stripped = ph.replace(/[\s()+-]|ext\.?/gi, "");
    // 10 is the minimum number of numbers required
    return ((/\d{10,}/i).test(stripped));
});

$('#custom').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        return true;
    }
}); 

<input type="text" class="phone" name="phone_1" id="phone_1">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to update your method so it returns true if the phone field is empty.
Something like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("phone", function(ph, element) {
    if(ph=='') return true;
    var stripped = ph.replace(/[\s()+-]|ext\.?/gi, "");
    // 10 is the minimum number of numbers required
    return ((/\d{10,}/i).test(stripped));
});
```

It's going to run the method on all of the phone fields, so this way you allow them to pass on untested unless they actually contain content.

Comment: Perfect! I wonder how we can change it to work for a _URL_ field?

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot :)