# Validate optional form fields with default values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Here's my javascript:

```
$("#cname, #cemail, #curl, #ccomment").focus(function(){
  if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
    $(this).val("");
  }
}).blur(function() {
  if( !this.value.length ) {
    $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
  }
});

$.validator.addMethod("noName", function(value, element) {
return value != element.defaultValue;
}, "Please enter your name.");
$.validator.addMethod("noComment", function(value, element) {
return value != element.defaultValue;
}, "Please enter your comment.");

$("#commentForm").validate();
```

The actual form:

```
  <form id="commentForm" action="">
   <p>
     <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required noName" value="Name">
   </p>
   <p>
     <input id="cemail" name="email" size="25" class="email" value="Email">
   </p>
   <p>
     <input id="curl" name="url" size="25" class="url" value="URL">
   </p>
   <p>
     <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" rows="5" cols="35" class="required noComment">Comment</textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </p>
 </form>
```

And here's a test:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/form-validation.html

If you click the submit button, you get error messages on *Email* and *URL* fields while they are optional. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute instead of filling in the value.

Comment: Unfortunately IE doesn't support it.

Comment: You can use the [jQuery Placeholder plugin](http://andrew-jones.com/jquery-placeholder-plugin/) to add support for it in browsers that don't have it natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach:  add an *igonre* class to *Email* and *URL* fields and removeClass / addClass on focus / blur. Test: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/form_validation.html

see [validate options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for more information.

Alternatively you can completely get rid of the class attribute and then:

on focus >> *this.className = 'url'*
on blur >> *this.className = ''*

without changing the validate call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the classes 'url' and 'email' for those two form fields, because the plugin is going to try and validate them because they are 'reserved' classes in the plugin .  I would suggest trying doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993356/how-to-add-custom-but-not-required-method-to-jquery-validation-plugin) for both the email and url fields.

I haven't tried this, but it suggests that you can custom, but not required field.

Comment: "You can't use the classes 'url' and 'email' for those two form fields" I do it deliberately to validate them but as _optional_ fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 placeholder element all the same, but test for placeholder support and then polyfill for it if not available, for example

```
//test
function placeholderIsSupported() {
    var test = document.createElement('input');
    return ('placeholder' in test);
}
//polyfill
if(!(placeholderIsSupported())) {
  $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
      input.removeClass('placeholder');
    }
  }).blur(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.addClass('placeholder');
      input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
  }).blur();
  $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function () {
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
      }
    })
  });
```

However, strictly speaking what you're doing is providing labels rather than example values for the inputs, so it would probably be more correct/standards-y to use elements `<label>` and position them behind the inputs, and then hide them when the inputs are focused/have non-empty values, eg:

HTML:

```
<p class="row">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required noName" value="">
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  position: relative;
}

input,
label {
  display: block
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  /*tweak these until label correctly positioned behind input*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: transparent;
}

input:focus,
input.has-value {
  background-color: #fff; //hide the label behind the bg color when focused or non-empty
}
```

jQuery:

```
//toggle a class depending on whether an input has content or not
input.on('blur', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val === "") {
    $this.removeClass('has-value');
  }
  else {
    $this.addClass('has-value');
  }
});
```

This second option is more semantic and more accessible too, given that screen reader support for `placeholder` is patchy

Comment: It seems like all he really needs to solve his original problem is your code that removes the default value in the `.submit` handler. The problem, in either case, is ensuring that his handler runs before the validate plugin's handler, so it doesn't see the defaults.

Comment: My point was really that even though that would solve the problem as the OP framed it, its much more graceful (and accessible) to use a label. Input values should be for exactly that - values - not labels.